# How to increase or decrease text font from Phonegap app

Tags: cordova

I want to increase or decrease text font size in PhoneGap app. I have implement some code and its working on browser but does not work on real device or simulator. So please suggest your answer.

Comment: Does setting the css value not work for you?

Comment: yes, nothing is working on device, rather its working on browser. So please you can share code as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an external css file, make sure you have included it by providing the right name of the css file. If there is any uppercase character in it's name, which you might have ignored, the browser will take the actual css, but the device wont take it.